# Basic Python interface to use with UHF RFID reader?

Tags: python, serial, rfid

I have a Chinese [UHF RFID reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VQ7DTP2) that I'm using with a RasPi for a warehouse tracking project and it came with only a Windows SDK. The dense protocol document they provided in very rough English is way over my head. All I need is a simple command to read the RFID data in Python or similar. I'm connecting over RS232 serial port.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what document are you talking about?

Comment: An example of using the serial port to read an RFID tag and play a corresponding sound file using Python. 
https://github.com/scivision/pyRFID

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: You get what you pay for. Get a reputable brand reader that comes with well-written documentation if you can't figure out how to use this one.